# how to create multiple questions in quiz project?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, fragment

I'm working on a quiz project. I want to have multiple questions which will be answered using drag and drop answers. I've done that and put it in an activity.
but I've just one question. I want to create multiple questions of that pattern. so how to do that ? using fragments maybe ?

[image: Drag and Drop]

Comment: Some code to show the issue would be nice.

Comment: Added image from link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your questions into an ArrayList called "questions" and all the possible answers for that question into another array "answers". The index of the answer will be the same with the index of the question to which that answer is.

Comment: You mean I don't need to create a fragment for each question, and I can do all that work in one activity ?

Comment: Yes , you only need one activity. Which will take the question and the possible answers from your arrays, in any order you want